# maven compile ambiguous when create custom interface CrudDao and CrudRepository (spring-data-jpa)

Tags: java, maven, spring-data-jpa

I made a interface CrudDao.java

```
public interface CrudDao<T extends Entity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> {
    <S extends T> save (S entity);
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericCrudDao<T extends GenericEntity> extends 
    CrudDao<T, Long>,
    JpaRespoitory<T, Long>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>,
    PagingAndSortingDao<T, Long> {

}
```

Then My real business dao is simply to extends the GenericDao. When I run build in Eclipse is fine, However, it can't compile in Maven.

It will show..

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] MemberService.java:[39,26] error: reference to save is ambiguous
[ERROR] both method <S#1>save(S#1) in CrudRepository and method <S#2>save(S#2) in CrudDao match
[ERROR] where S#1,T#1,S#2,T#2,ID are type-variables:
[ERROR] S#1 extends T#1 declared in method <S#1>save(S#1)
[ERROR] T#1 extends Object declared in interface CrudRepository
[ERROR] S#2 extends T#2 declared in method <S#2>save(S#2)
[ERROR] T#2 extends Entity<ID> declared in interface CrudDao
[ERROR] ID extends Serializable declared in interface CrudDao
```

The Entity is extends GenericEntity extends Entity. Why maven-compiler will ambiguously the CurdDao.save(Entity) and CrudRespository.save(Object). and How can I change the codes let maven compile to success ?

Comment: Maven just invokes `javac`. Eclipse has its own compiler. Why are you extending all those interfaces anyway?

Comment: You wouldn't have such issues if your `CrudDao` extended `PagingAndSortingRepository` directly.

Comment: the CrudDao extends PagingAndSortingDao, not PagingAndSortingRepository.

Comment: @NoRepositoryBean
public interface PagingAndSortingDao<T extends Entity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> {

 Long countByCondition(final T entity);

 List<T> findByCondition(final T entity, final Pageable pageable);

}

Comment: Try to build with command line. If you succeed, then it is Eclipse configuration issue